# redux-form - Uncaught Error: `mapDispatchToProps`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am receiving the following error in the console when I try to navigate to a signin form:

```
Uncaught Error: `mapDispatchToProps` must return an object. Instead received function () {
              return computedActions;
            }.
    at Object.invariant [as default] (bundle.js:21392)
    at computeDispatchProps (bundle.js:19996)
    at new Connect (bundle.js:20049)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:7346)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as mountComponent] (bundle.js:1536)
    at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js:5728)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:7423)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as mountComponent] (bundle.js:1536)
    at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js:5728)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (bundle.js:14298)
```

Here is the file in question (signin.js):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';

class Signin extends Component {
    handleFormSubmit({email, password}) {
        console.log( email, password );
    }

    render() {

        const {handleSubmit, fields: {email, password}} = this.props;

        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
                <fieldset className="form-group">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input {...email} className="form-control"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset className="form-group">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input {...password} className="form-control"/>
                </fieldset>
                <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'signin',
    fields: ['email', 'password']
})(Signin);
```

The view "signin.js" worked fine until I added in the code for redux-form.  Here are the versions of react, redux, redux-form I am using:

```
"react": "^0.14.3",
"react-dom": "^0.14.3",
"react-redux": "4.0.0",
"react-router": "^2.0.1",
"redux": "^3.0.4",
"redux-form": "^6.6.3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux-form v6 doesn't support config property `fields`, it was supported in previous versions.
To create a field you should use components `Field, FieldArray or Fields`.

Take a look on documentation, http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem here

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
```

You are providing a function as a parameter to `handleSubmit` which inturn retuns a value to `onSubmit`

Try this

```
class Signin extends Component {

    render() {

        const {handleSubmit, fields: {email, password}} = this.props;

        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <fieldset className="form-group">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input {...email} className="form-control"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset className="form-group">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input {...password} className="form-control"/>
                </fieldset>
                <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

And in the parentComponent ou will have the handleSubmit function like

```
handleSubmit = ({email, password}) => {
    console.log(email, password);   //Do what you want with values here
}
```